# Cohomology theory for generalized smooth spaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, cohomology, topos-theory, generalized-smooth-spaces

Is there a cohomology theory for generalized smooth spaces, for example, smooth topos?

In particular, if we know the cohomology of $M$ and $N$, can we calculate that  of $M^N$?

Comment: A smooth topos is a ringed topos, so there's a notion of cohomology.

Comment: Where can I read the cohomology theory of ringed topos?

Comment: For now, I just can remember Monique Hakim thesis, but maybe other standard books on elementary topos will have something, like Johnstone's book "Topos theory" or "Sketches of an elephant". Actually, for any topos the abelian group objects will form an abelian category and you have the global sections functor (the unique morphism to the terminal topos of sets), then you can just apply the usual machinery of cohomological functors and pick the derived functor of global sections.

Comment: It's moreover a Grothendieck topos, so all of Tohoku applies.

Comment: A good introductory exposition is a paper by Freed and Hopkins, Chern-Weil forms and abstract homotopy theory.